# jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy

Tags: jquery, webpack, jestjs

I have a function in a module called button-actions that is called when a user clicks a back button. I want to test the backButtonActions method directly but need to mock up the leaveApp and displayById methods inside backButtonActions that get called.

Here is my **button-actions.js** file method.

```
export function backButtonActions( label, page ){      //, page
    console.log("LABEL = ", label, "  page = ", page);
    switch( label ){
        case 'step1':
            page.leaveApp();
            break;
        case 'step2':
            page.displayById();
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm new to tests so I might be missing something very simple. 
Below is my **test.js** file

```
   window.$ = require('jquery');
    import {backButtonActions} from '../button-actions';


    describe('Button Actions', () => {

        const page = {}

        beforeEach(() => {

            page.leaveApp = jest.fn(() => "leave");
            page.displayById = jest.fn(() => "Display");

            document.body.innerHTML =
                '<div>' +
                '  <button class="btn-back" />' +
                '</div>';

                 $('.btn-back').click((event, label) =>{
                     backButtonActions( label, page );
                 });




    });
    it('backButtonActions requires a string of either "step1" or "step2"', () => {

        $('.btn-back').trigger('click', 'step1');

         expect(backButtonActions).toBeCalled();
         expect(backButtonActions).toBeCalledWith("step1" || "step2");
    });
})
```

When I run the above test I get the following error.

> ● Button Actions › backButtonActions requires a string of either
>   "step 1" or "step 2"
>
> ```
> expect(jest.fn())[.not].toBeCalled()
>
> jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
> Received:
>   function: [Function backButtonActions]
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (test/js/spec/create/button-actions.test.js:64:50)
> ```

Is there something else I should be running to get this to work ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to spy on the `backButtonActions` function, either via jasmine's `spyOn` method or via Jest's `jest.spyOn` method

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: Accordind to jest Mock functions are also known as "spies", because they let you spy on the behavior of a function that is called indirectly by some other code, rather than just testing the output. You can create a mock function with jest.fn(). If no implementation is given, the mock function will return undefined when invoked. Now I'm confused can you explain the difference between jest.fn and jest.spyOn

Comment: Any chance of an example as it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Try this: instead of `import {backButtonActions} from '../button-actions';` Try `import * as buttonActions from '../button-actions';`. Then change all references to `backButtonActions` to `buttonActions.backButtonActions`. Then in the first line of your test, you can spy on `buttonActions.backButtonActions`: `jest.SpyOn(buttonActions, 'backButtonActions');`

Answer (score 3):

An example, as it took me a while as well to figure out:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(XYZComponent, {
  global: {
    mocks: {
      ...,
    },
  },
});
...

test('it should ...', () => {
  jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.$refs.refOnElement, 'customElementMethodToBeMocked').mockImplementation();
  wrapper.vm.componentMethodWhereYouCallCustomElementMethodToBeMocked();
  expect(wrapper.vm.$refs.refOnElement.customElementMethodToBeMocked).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```